# Generate list from string with proper encoding (UTF-8)

Tags: python, json, list, utf-8

I'm having a hard time trying to generate a list from a string, with a proper UTF-8 encoding, I'm using Python (I'm just learning to program, so bare with my silly question/terrible coding).

The source file is a tweet feed (JSON format), after parsing it successfully and extracting the tweet message from all the rest I manage to get the text with the right encoding only after a print (as a string). If I try to put it pack into list forms, it goes back to unencoded `u\000000` form.

My code is:

```
import json

with open("file_name.txt") as tweets_file:
    tweets_list = [] 
    for a in tweets_file:
        b = json.loads(a)
        tweets_list.append(b)

    tweet = []
    for i in tweets_list:
        key = "text"
        if key in i:
            t = i["text"]
            tweet.append(t)

    for k in tweet:
        print k.encode("utf-8")
```

As an alternative, I tried to have the encoding at the beginning (when fetching the file):

```
import json
import codecs

tweets_file = codecs.open("file_name.txt", "r", "utf-8")
tweets_list = [] 
for a in tweets_file:
    b = json.loads(a)
    tweets_list.append(b)
tweets_file.close()

tweet = []
for i in tweets_list:
    key = "text"
    if key in i:
        t = i["text"]
        tweet.append(t)

for k in tweet:
    print k
```

**My question is**: how can I put the resulting k strings, into a list? With each k string as an item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting confused by the Python string representation.

When you print a python list (or any other standard Python container), the contents are shown in special representation to make debugging easier; each value is shown is the result of calling the [`repr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on that value. For string  values, that means the result is a *unicode string representation*, and that is not the same thing as what you see when the string is printed directly.

Unicode and byte strings, when shown like that, are presented as string literals; quoted values that you can copy and paste straight back into Python code without having to worry about encoding; anything that is not a printable ASCII character is shown in quoted form. Unicode code points beyond the latin-1 plane are shown as `'\u....'` escape sequences. Characters in the latin-1 range use the `'\x..` escape sequence. Many control characters are shown in their 1-letter escape form, such as `\n` and `\t`.

The python interactive prompt does the same thing; when you echo a value on the prompt *without* using `print`, the value in 'represented', shown in the `repr()` form:

```
>>> print u'\u2036Hello World!\u2033'
‶Hello World!″
>>> u'\u2036Hello World!\u2033'
u'\u2036Hello World!\u2033'
>>> [u'\u2036Hello World!\u2033', u'Another\nstring']
[u'\u2036Hello World!\u2033', u'Another\nstring']
>>> print _[1]
Another
string
```

This *entirly normal* behaviour. In other words, your code **works**, nothing is broken.

To come back to your code, if you want to extract just the `'text'` key from the tweet JSON structures, filter while reading the file, don't bother with looping twice:

```
import json

with open("file_name.txt") as tweets_file:
    tweets = [] 
    for line in tweets_file:
        data = json.loads(a)
        if 'text' in data:
            tweets.append(data['text'])
```

Comment: I see... so what I see is not what I really get.

I have to admit, I thought it was something to do with the 'rendering' more than the 'actuality' of the thing. 
Thank you very much Martijn!